Check the equality of IEnumerable<char>'s case-insensitive in an optimal way
I try to write my own version of the string, and I didn't understand yet how to check the equality of such strings (inherited from IEnumerable<char>) case-insensitively.
Of course, this code:
if (_size != other._size)
    return false;
for (var i = 0; i < _size && i < other._size; i++)
    if (char.ToUpper(this[i]) != char.ToUpper(other[i]))
        return false;
return true;

is not optimal. (The _size variable means length, but is a private variable that can be changed inside the class.) This code calls char.ToUpper() two times, whereas I just need to compare that chars. What is a better way?
Note: check must work for all writing systems like Latin, Cyrillic, Arabic etc.

What sort of case-insensitivity to you want? Should it be culture-sensitive, ordinal? Invariant-culture-sensitive? See StringComparer for details of some of the options you might want to consider...

Also, do you have access to a ReadOnlySpan<char> rather than just an IEnumerable<char>? If so, CompareInfo may well help you a lot...

Hello @JonSkeet! I didn't think about different sorts of case-insensitivity but probably the good string implementation has to support all of them. About ReadOnlySpan - my string internally uses unsafe pointer to char, and it probably can be converted to ReadOnlySpan, but is this an optimal way?

That sounds optimal to me, yes - basically it would allow you to delegate as much work as possible to the framework.
